# How to read all csv files in a folder in pandas?

Tags: pandas, directory

Every month I am downloading the whole ledger in csv format and saving the same to a folder. How I can read it in pandas as single dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

Answer (score 8):

**fthomson's** answer but the last line should be

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = glob.glob("path/*.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.append(csv)
```

Comment: This answer is NOT it. Never append DataFrames repeatedly in a loop as it repeatedly allocated memory! Every `df.append` copies the entire DataFrame. ni1o1's answer is to be used.

Answer (score 7):

This is a faster way. Append small DataFrame after large DataFrame will cost a lot. So a better way is to append all DataFrame into one list and use `pd.concat` to concat all DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = glob.glob("path/*.csv")
df = []
for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.append(csv)
df = pd.concat(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this from memory but this is the general idea

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = glob.glob("path/*.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.append(csv)
```