# Rename column and reformat data of multiple CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a folder CSV files containing lines as follows:

```
Date      | A | B | C |
2021-10-11| A | B | C |
```

I would like to rearrange the date column across every file, for instance, from 2021-10-11 to 10/11/2021.

Comment: "I would like to rearrange the date column across every file" An admirable goal. What have you tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with _code_ so that we can better understand how to help

Comment: @G.Anderson havent really tried not sure how

Comment: [How to change the datetime format in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38067704/15497888), [Renaming column names in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11346283/15497888), [How to read all csv files in a folder in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65132425/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

## Use the pathlib, datetime and csv modules

To import your data use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module and flip the dates you will need a csv reader and a csv writer.
Using the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) classes can be convenient.

Converting dates is pretty simple using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

old_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
new_fmt = '%m/%d/%Y'

def process_file(path):
    # read the data in
    with path.open('r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        fieldnames = reader.fieldnames
        data = list(reader)

    # write the data out
    with path.open('w') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            # here we convert the format
            dt = datetime.strptime(row['date'], old_fmt)
            row['date'] = dt.strftime(new_fmt)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

[pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is a great module for working with the filesystem.
Its easy to process all the files.

```py
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('path/to/directory')

for path in folder.iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        process_file(path)
```